# Issue implementing git add/commit in sh python module

Tags: python, git

I am experiencing the following strange behavior with git from sh python module:

**Here is the python script:**

```
import sh
from datetime import datetime

now = str(datetime.now())

filename = "config.cfg"
file = filename
f = open(file, 'w')
f.write(now)

now = str(datetime.now())
comment = "-m " + "\"new version" + " registrered " + now + "\""


print(sh.sudo.git("add", filename))
print(sh.sudo.git("commit", comment))
```

**BEHAVIOR:
Manually everything works fine:**

```
$ echo "new content" > config.cfg
$ git add config.cfg
$ sudo git commit -m "ospf configuration registrered 2014-10-24 15:30:33.531963"
[master 142cfd5] ospf configuration registrered 2014-10-24 15:30:33.531963
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

But not the implementation through python sh module

**I-### 1st execution is OK**

```
python sh1.py
[master 6d13519]  "new version registrered 2014-10-24 15:37:42.534595"
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
```

**II-### any further execution gives the following:**

```
python sh1.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sh1.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(sh.sudo.git("commit", comment))
  File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 769, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 330, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 334, in wait
    self._handle_exit_code(self.process.wait())
  File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 348, in _handle_exit_code
    self.process.stderr
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: '/usr/bin/sudo git commit -m "new version registrered 2014-10-24 15:38:02.528213"'

  STDOUT:
On branch master
Untracked files:
    sh1.py

nothing added to commit but untracked files present


  STDERR:
```

**III- ### everything works fine after manual add and commit:**

```
$ sudo git add config.cfg

$ sudo git commit -m "new version registrered 2014-10-24 15:34:35.2415245"
[master 5d5fe35] new version registrered 2014-10-24 15:34:35.2415245
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

And now back to 1st behavior I, and so on...

---

The user is in sudoers and set NOPASSWD to avoid sudo password

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to close the file object before you invoke the git commands.

```
f.close()
```

If you ran 'git status', you'd see that Git was complaining that after the script ran, config.cfg still had changes that were unstaged for commit.

<s>I have a feeling that python flushes an EOF character or something to the file when it's closed, and therefore alters the file since you called 'git add' from your script.</s>  I don't know for sure unfortunately, only that the issue was resolved for me when I closed the file prior to 'git add' 'git commit' from the script.

Edit:
Useless has corrected me and noted that the reason is because the file is buffered.

Comment: The file is buffered - there's no EOF, just a change that wasn't flushed to disk.

Comment: Can confirm.  File is definitely buffered.

Comment: Thanks Guys. Issue resolved, your answer is definitly useful P-